# Why can't we copy file descriptors just by plainly assigning the value to new variables?

Tags: c, file, low-level

I'm baffled about file descriptors. I understand that to copy them, we need the system call dup2() or dup(). But why can't we just copy them by assigning old values to new variables? For instance, why can we do this

```
int f[2];
pipe(f); // I call pipe just to create two file descriptors, nothing special
int new_descriptor = f[0]; // this line is where I'm confused
```

Is is because the integers that f[0],f[1] have specific meaning, and are some sort of encoded?
Thanks!

Comment: `dup` creates and returns a new fd that points at the same file. The fd is an index into the processes file table, so `dup` actually finds the next open spot on the processes file table, copies the pointer to the (in kernel) file structure to that spot and returns the index to user space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy file descriptors by assignment.  What you can't do is change the file that a specific file descriptor number (such as `1`) refers to — to do that, you need `dup()` or `dup2()` — or `fcntl()`, or `close()`.  (Calls such as `open()` or `pipe()` don't affect any already-open file descriptors; they return a new one not previously in use.)

One way to look at it: there's nothing distinctive about the variable that holds the file descriptor number — any `int` variable holding the same number can be used as a file descriptor.  But changing the file that the file descriptor refers to is a much more complex job and requires a system call.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! :)

Comment: Great answer. I would add that calling `dup` or `dup2` increases the reference count for an open file, so closing the original file descriptor doesn't close the file, which is still accessible using the new file descriptor that `dup` returned (the file is only closed when the reference count reaches 0).

Comment: @Myst:  Correct, but I was planning to stay clear of the difference between open file descriptors and open file descriptions, both of which are separate from an 'open file'  because a single file could be opened several times with different open file descriptors.

Comment: Aargh!  I meant 'different open file descriptions' in the last sentence of my previous comment.